# Mockito for int primitive

Tags: java, mockito

If I am using a Wrapper class type variable as argument Mockito test case is getting pass but,
how to write Mockito test case for int primitive type variable which is an argument to a method in ServiceImpl.

Comment: Post the method under test, and the code you tried to test it.

Answer (score 62):

You may have some trouble with `any` or `argThat` for primitive-type arguments to `when` and `verify`. Those Object-centric methods do their work with side-effects correctly, but they tend to return `null` for a dummy return value, which doesn't work for Java unwrapping primitives via auto-boxing.

Luckily, the `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` class has a full complement of primitive-centric methods (of which I've listed the `int` methods here):

```
static int anyInt()
static int eq(int value)
static int intThat(org.hamcrest.ArgumentMatcher<java.lang.Integer> matcher)
```

See all of them at the [documentation for the ArgumentMatchers class](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html).

Comment: +1.  This is the right way to do it.  `anyInt()` is particularly useful.

Comment: I got error messages about misplaced argument matchers in verify() when I used any() for an int parameter. Very tricky... thank you for clarifying this

Comment: @AndrewP I'm glad, but surprised, that this answer helped with that exception—a bit like hearing "your answer about circuit breakers fixed my toilet flush". It may be worth surrounding the offending statement with `validateMockitoUsage` and checking that you're calling the overload you're intending. Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 6):

I know that the question has been more than 4 years and 8 months old but for the sake of clear solution as of ***today***, I am posting this

In my case, the method signature to be tested is

```
public SomeObject create(String code, int status)
```

so the test code for verifying the argument values when the method was invoked would be following

```
verify(this.service).create(
        argThat(code -> "dummy_code".equals(code)),
        intThat(status -> status == 105));
```

If I go with the *argThat* even for int (or any primitive types) then mockito throws [NPE](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/822)

Currently I am using *org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0* which must have been advanced considering the time when the question was asked! But thinking that this might be helpful to people... Thanks,