# Mockito matching primitive types

Tags: java, mockito

I am getting an exception when setting up a mock using Mockito:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
```

The set up code is this:

```
Mockito
    .when(aMock.method(any(), any()))
    .thenReturn(something);
```

Where `method` expects two `double` arguments.

Comment: Please check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980728/mockito-for-int-primitive/53331588 using that you can verify any primitive type arguments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`any()` returns `null`. This choice was inevitable because the signature of `any()` is

```
public static <T> T any()
```

Since generic types are erased in Java, and since nothing is passed to the method that carries any type information (such as a `Class<T>`), `null` is the only reasonable return value.

This creates a problem if the method of the mock has an argument of primitive type because unboxing this `null` value throws a `NullPointerException`.

There are two possible solutions. You can either use the primitive versions (such as `anyDouble()`), or the version accepting a `Class` (e.g. `any(Double.class)`). In the latter case, since we are supplying type information to the method, it is possible to use this information to return a sensible non-null value (e.g. `0.0D` in the case of double).

Answer (score 8):

The reason for the error is a little contrived - `any()` cannot be used in place of primitive data types.

`anyChar()`, `anyDouble()` etc. must be used instead for primitive types.

Comment: Presumably `anyDouble()` in this particular case?