# How to use Mockito.spy with matchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Let's say that I define a spy object.

```
MyClass myClass = spy(new MyClass());
```

Let's suppose that MyClass includes a method:

```
public boolean isEven(int number) {
   return number % 2 == 0;
}
```

Now, I want to mock specific method in the class, for example:

```
doReturn(true).when(myClass).someMethod(Matchers.any());
```

Then I get the error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
> Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
> Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
> when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
> doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
> verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

In all code examples that I see, doReturn(...).when(spyObject).method(arg1, arg2, ...)
works only for specific arguments.

My question is how we can mock a method in spy object for matcher arguments.

Comment: please provide signature of method `MyClass#someMethod` - as it can be useful to see the minimal code that helps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Daniel I edited the post

Comment: I think that this comment can be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996892/13608717